# Firebase setPersistenceEnabled bug remove data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created an application for android to allowed an association to share some events with their community. I used firebase to stored the data of these events.

When an administrator remove an event (in the app). This event is removed from the database and for all user who had the app opened. After this, if the other user opens her app, the event who was removed will be re-upload on the database.

The Persistence is enabled to allow the usage without networks. I don't know how it's possible for firebase to update the database with the values contained in the "Firebase cache."

Does anyone have an idea why the data came back after their delete?

Comment: If the app is offline at the time a query is performed, it will be satisfied by the local cache.  If the app is online and able to sync, you shouldn't see deleted data in queries.

Comment: yes but the app offline doesn't execute any query. It's like if when the app offline became online they push the caches whereas the app should juste update the value with the database content

Comment: The cache isn't updated automatically. An online query would force the sync.

Comment: Indeed but it's just the push of the caches who are strange

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "push of the caches".  Cache is only updated at the time of a query.

Comment: Thanks for your help @DougStevenson, i solved my bug

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this bug is due to a difference between the versions of the application that had the different users.

In the last version i had :

```
databaseRef.keepSynced(true)
```